# Can any one help me to convert this sql query into ruby query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby and i am not able to convert the given query into ruby query, can any one help me for that

```
"SELECT * FROM domainurls WHERE domaindetail_id = ?",@domain.id ,"and count IN (SELECT Max( count ) FROM domainurls WHERE domaindetail_id =?",@domain.id")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Domainurl.
  where(:domaindetail_id => @domain.id).
  where("count IN (SELECT MAX(count) FROM domainurls WHERE domaindetail_id = ? ", @domain.id)
```